# pandas get days in a column from start date?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, python-datetime

pandas get days in a column from start date?

start_date = '01/01/2021' (dd/mm/yyyy)

df

```
    dates

    2021-01-01
    2021-01-02
    .
    .
    .
    2021-02-01
    .
    .
    .
    2021-06-01           (end date should be current date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is always `1.1.` pandas parse datetimes like `mm/dd/YYYY` so because same day and month here working well only passing string to [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and `now`, default `period='D'`, so omitted:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.date_range(start_date, pd.to_datetime('now'))})
```

General solution with convert `start_date` by format `dd/mm/YYYY` is parsed also `start_date` with `format` parameter:

```
start_date = '01/05/2021'

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(start_date, format='%d/%m/%Y'), 
                                          pd.to_datetime('now'))})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wand a dataframe output :

```
d = pd.date_range(start_date, pd.to_datetime('now'))
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': d})
```